# What are the available Signals in Java

Tags: java, signals

What are the names of signals available in Java with this code:

```
new sun.misc.Signal(signalStr);
```

And what are the corresponding integer values?

I could not find any official documentation except [this one](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ztpf/2022?topic=signals-used-by-jvm) and this is for only IBM JDK.
When I trace the code I saw that it calls some native code which are implemented in JVM.

Comment: `new Signal`? Signal is not part of the standard JDK classes. When asking questions about types, always include the fully qualified name, and the source of that type (which library). Because otherwise, potential answerers have no idea what you're talking about!

Comment: Signal is OS signal, the tag also describes this thing. The corresponding Java package of Signal is sun.misc in standard JDK at least until for the JDK 17. I edited and added the package.

Comment: My `sun.misc.Signal` is in module `jdk-unsupported` which sounds like a pretty strong hint.  As the docs say, "This class provides ANSI/ISO C signal support." - it's not java that gets to define the signals, it's your OS that defines them and java merely echoes these. So, look for your standard docs on signals for linux, windows, etc.

Comment: Signal may not be recommended to use BUT there is NO alternative way (yet) to directly handle signals on Java and I strongly hope they will create something better when they decided to remove this class. Also that is part of the standard JDK classes, when you write my original code to an IDE it will suggest import from only the sun.misc package so your first comment was misleading (anyway I already added the package) which probably caused to be closed my valid question.

Comment: So if you think that the sentence you quoted is enough to answer my question, then can you just please what are the name/number pairs for each/any platform? Where are those lists? On Windows OS there is no integer numbers for signals, so JVM developers should map them to some integers but which ones are my question.. Also I shared the IBM document so IBM thought that those pairs may be required for somebody and did not say "you can find it".

Comment: Do you know for sure that this API works on Windows?  If it's a C signal I would expect the numbers to be in signal.h.  I can see the `signal` C function on Windows does take an integer but you should use #define'd names and the doc doesn't give the integer values directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xdkz3x12(v=vs.140)

Comment: Yes @Jayen I also found the signal.h source today. If the question will open (1 more vote is required to repoen) then I will have a good answer to share with everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I brute forced the single to 5 character length signals and got these:

```
BREAK (21)
SEGV (11)
ILL (4)
FPE (8)
TERM (15)
ABRT (22)
INT (2)
```

The code:

```
Set<String> signals = new HashSet<>();
    String currentSignalStr;
    for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++) {
        for (char j = 'A'; j <= 'Z'; j++) {
            for (char k = 'A'; k <= 'Z'; k++) {
                for (char l = 'A'; l <= 'Z'; l++) {
                    for (char m = 'A'; m <= 'Z'; m++) {
                        try {
                            currentSignalStr = "" + i + j + k + l + m;
                            new Signal(currentSignalStr);
                            signals.add(currentSignalStr);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        currentSignalStr = "" + i + j + k + l;
                        new Signal(currentSignalStr);
                        signals.add(currentSignalStr);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                try {
                    currentSignalStr = "" + i + j + k;
                    new Signal(currentSignalStr);
                    signals.add(currentSignalStr);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            try {
                currentSignalStr = "" + i + j;
                new Signal(currentSignalStr);
                signals.add(currentSignalStr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        try {
            currentSignalStr = "" + i;
            new Signal(currentSignalStr);
            signals.add(currentSignalStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Of course, these are valid for my Windows 10 x64 and OpenJDK 17, but anyone can use the same method to get their own list. (Share if any found!)

After that I looked into OpenJDK source code (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/45ff10cc68296c7c73d0eafe6fcc9946ab98267e/src/hotspot/os/windows/os_windows.cpp) they use these signals. And corresponding integer numbers come from signal.h import which I guess is a Linux file (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/signal.h) more concisely it is the C library of the compiler used for OpenJDK build.